# Converting a code from bash to php

Tags: bash

I currently have an existing code in bash that greps a keyword from a config file:

```
    [USER1]
    usrcid = 5654654654
    usrsid = XDFDFSAS22
    usrmid = COMPANYNAME1
    usrsrt = secret1
    urlenc = http://www.url1.com

    [USER2]
    usrcid = 5654654667
    usrsid = XDFDFSAS45
    usrmid = COMPANYNAME2
    usrsrt = secret2
    urlenc = http://www.url2.com
```

I store it as a variable and use it for processing the rest of the script. What I want to achieve is to convert the behavior from bash to php and do a curl:

```
    F1=/etc/config/file.txt
    CID=`grep "\[USER1\]" -A 5 $F1 | grep usrcid | awk {'print$3'}`
    SID=`grep "\[USER1\]" -A 5 $F1 | grep usrsid | awk {'print$3'}`
    MID=`grep "\[USER1\]" -A 5 $F1 | grep usrmid | awk {'print$3'}`
    SRT=`grep "\[USER1\]" -A 5 $F1 | grep usrsrt | awk {'print$3'}`
    URI=`grep "\[USER1\]" -A 5 $F1 | grep urlenc | awk {'print$3'}`
    echo $CID $SID $MID $SRT $URI
```

I'm really not a php guru so please excuse the code below but from a general perspective, the below code is my understanding of what I want to achieve:

```
    <?php
    include "/etc/config/file.txt"

    // *** the equivalent code grep? ***

    function get_data($url)
    {
     $ch = curl_init();
         $timeout = 5;
         curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
         curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
         curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
         $data = curl_exec($ch);
         curl_close($ch);
         return $data;
    }

    // *** i'm not sure if this one is correct? ***

$returned_content = get_data('$URI/cid=$CID&sid=$SID&mid=$MID&srt=$SRT')
    echo $returned_content;
    ?>
```

This is my first time to ask in stackoverflow so I would like to thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include doesn't do what you think it's doing. It won't get the variables you set in the text-file. If it were PHP code in the file you included, it would evaluate that, but in this case, it's only text. See the [Manual](http://no.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

What you need is to use the parse_ini_file() function. It takes the config file as first argument, and a boolean flag as the second. The second argument is used to let the function know that you should use sections in your config file, which you do.

**Example:**

file.txt:

```
[USER1]
usrcid = 5654654654
usrsid = XDFDFSAS22
usrmid = COMPANYNAME1
usrsrt = secret1
urlenc = http://www.url1.com

[USER2]
usrcid = 5654654667
usrsid = XDFDFSAS45
usrmid = COMPANYNAME2
usrsrt = secret2
urlenc = http://www.url2.com
```

test.php:

```
<?php

$config = parse_ini_file("file.txt", true);

print_r($config);

?>
```

*(See the manual for [`parse_ini_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php))*

This will load the config file to the `$config` variable, and it will contain the following:

```
Array
(
    [USER1] => Array
        (
            [usrcid] => 5654654654
            [usrsid] => XDFDFSAS22
            [usrmid] => COMPANYNAME1
            [usrsrt] => secret1
            [urlenc] => http://www.url1.com
        )

    [USER2] => Array
        (
            [usrcid] => 5654654667
            [usrsid] => XDFDFSAS45
            [usrmid] => COMPANYNAME2
            [usrsrt] => secret2
            [urlenc] => http://www.url2.com
        )

)
```

Now, to construct an URL you could use:

```
$url = "{$config['USER1']['urlenc']}/cid={$config['USER1']['usrcid']}&sid={$config['USER1']['usrsid']}&mid={$config['USER1']['usrmid']}&srt={$config['USER1']['usrsrt']}";
```

Or construct a dynamic way of iterating through the array given in the $config variable, to account for several sections. This URL you can run through the cURL function you got.